# Why doesn't instantiating an object automatically instantiate its properties?

Tags: c#, .net, instance

I have the following classes:

```
public class CustomerResult
{
    public string CompanyStatus { get; set; }
    public OverallResult Result { get; set; }
}

public class OverallResult
{
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }        
}
```

I instantiate:

```
var apiResult = new CustomerResult();
```

Why does the following return a null reference? Surely `OverallResult` is instantiated when I create `CustomerResult()`?

```
apiResult.Result.CustomerId = "12345";
```

Comment: No it isn't instantiated. Primitive values will hold a default for you automatically, it won't create an instance of an object however that is your `OverallResult`.

Comment: Why would the `OverallResult Result` property be instantiated when there is no code to perform that instantiation?  Instantiating an object does not automatically instantiate all of its properties.

Comment: There is no `new OverallResult();` in your code.

Comment: I've tried to give you a better title.  Please feel free to edit it if you feel I missed the mark.

Comment: That is why programmers think it is useful to write a constructor.  Make it so.

Comment: It's Friday and it's been a long week - had a proper brain fade!

Comment: `null` is the default value for a reference.

Comment: I suspect you may be reasoning about C# as though it was C++.  C# is not C++, a property is not a field, and reference types are different than value types. Are there any of these points that you are confused about? If so, ask a more targeted question and we can try to resolve your confusion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you didn't create an instance for `Result`. Reference types have null values by default and `OverallResult` is a class, hence a reference type.

You can do it in constructor.

```
public class CustomerResult
{
    public string CompanyStatus { get; set; }
    public OverallResult Result { get; set; }
    public CustomerResult(){
        Result = new OverallResult();
    }
}
```

---

if your `C#` version heigher than 6.0 there is a simpler way [Auto-Property Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#auto-property-initializers)

> C# 6 enables you to assign an initial value for the storage used by an auto-property in the auto-property declaration:

```
public class CustomerResult
{
    public string CompanyStatus { get; set; }
    public OverallResult Result { get; set; } = new OverallResult();
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting the auto-properties used in #6 forward compile to setting the properties in the constructor like in the first example.  Syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons that child objects are not automatically instantiated is that you may not want to call the default constructor, or even you want to force the programmer to call the constructor with enough parameters to correctly initialise the class fully, so there isn't a public default constructor.

You could argue that if there is a default constructor then it should always run, followed by the one you actually want, but then you are doing the same work twice.

```
public class CustomerResult
{
   public string CompanyStatus { get; set; }
   public OverallResult Result { get; set; }
}

public class OverallResult
{
   public OverallResult()
   {
       StatusCode = 55;
       StatusDescription = "Nothing to see";
   }
   public OverallResult(int statusCode, string status)
   {
      StatusCode = statusCode;
      StatusDescription = status;
   }
   public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
   public int StatusCode { get; set; }
   public string CustomerId { get; set; }        
}

void main()
{
   var result = new CustomerResult()
   {
       Result = new OverallResult(51, "Blah"),
   };
}
```